# Payara5 Server will not deploy: Unknown Protocol RFB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, server, glassfish, payara

In a clean eclipse environment payara5 will not deploy. I have downloaded the correct version of the server, using java 1.8 and simply added it with new server to start it. I cannot get rid of this error. The payara landing page works, however  administrative console timeouts. Any help aprreciated.

```
    2019-10-23T13:13:32.432+0200|INFORMATION: Running Payara Version: Payara Server  5.193.1 #badassfish (build 275)
2019-10-23T13:13:32.438+0200|INFORMATION: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
2019-10-23T13:13:33.015+0200|INFORMATION: Registered fish.payara.ha.hazelcast.store.HazelcastBackingStoreFactoryProxy for persistence-type = hazelcast in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2019-10-23T13:13:33.173+0200|INFORMATION: Network Listener http-listener-1 started in: 18ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
2019-10-23T13:13:33.202+0200|INFORMATION: Network Listener http-listener-2 started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
2019-10-23T13:13:33.213+0200|INFORMATION: Network Listener admin-listener started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
2019-10-23T13:13:33.215+0200|INFORMATION: Grizzly 2.4.3 started in: 352ms - bound to [http-listener-1:8080, http-listener-2:8181, admin-listener:4848]
2019-10-23T13:13:33.305+0200|INFORMATION: Network Listener iiop-service started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
2019-10-23T13:13:33.404+0200|INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.16.Final
2019-10-23T13:13:35.437+0200|WARNUNG: [172.30.241.97]:4900 [development] [3.12] Connection[id=3, /172.30.241.97:53016->/172.30.241.97:5900, qualifier=null, endpoint=[172.30.241.97]:5900, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=3, /172.30.241.97:53016->/172.30.241.97:5900, qualifier=null, endpoint=[172.30.241.97]:5900, alive=true, type=NONE], thread=hz._hzInstance_1_development.IO.thread-out-1
java.io.IOException: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioOutboundPipeline.flushToSocket(NioOutboundPipeline.java:273)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioOutboundPipeline.process(NioOutboundPipeline.java:207)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioPipeline.run(NioPipeline.java:227)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processTaskQueue(NioThread.java:341)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:276)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:235)

2019-10-23T13:13:35.437+0200|WARNUNG: [172.30.241.97]:4900 [development] [3.12] Connection[id=1, /10.82.9.38:53013->/10.82.9.38:5900, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.82.9.38]:5900, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=1, /10.82.9.38:53013->/10.82.9.38:5900, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.82.9.38]:5900, alive=true, type=NONE], thread=hz._hzInstance_1_development.IO.thread-out-2
java.io.IOException: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioOutboundPipeline.flushToSocket(NioOutboundPipeline.java:273)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioOutboundPipeline.process(NioOutboundPipeline.java:207)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioPipeline.run(NioPipeline.java:227)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processTaskQueue(NioThread.java:341)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:276)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:235)

2019-10-23T13:13:35.437+0200|WARNUNG: [172.30.241.97]:4900 [development] [3.12] Connection[id=4, /10.0.75.1:53015->/10.0.75.1:5900, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.0.75.1]:5900, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=4, /10.0.75.1:53015->/10.0.75.1:5900, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.0.75.1]:5900, alive=true, type=NONE], thread=hz._hzInstance_1_development.IO.thread-out-0
java.io.IOException: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioOutboundPipeline.flushToSocket(NioOutboundPipeline.java:273)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioOutboundPipeline.process(NioOutboundPipeline.java:207)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioPipeline.run(NioPipeline.java:227)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processTaskQueue(NioThread.java:341)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:276)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:235)
```

and

```
2019-10-23T13:13:39.427+0200|WARNUNG: [172.30.241.97]:4900 [development] [3.12] Connection[id=18, /192.168.56.1:53035->/192.168.56.1:5900, qualifier=null, endpoint=[192.168.56.1]:5900, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=18, /192.168.56.1:53035->/192.168.56.1:5900, qualifier=null, endpoint=[192.168.56.1]:5900, alive=true, type=NONE], thread=hz._hzInstance_1_development.IO.thread-in-1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: RFB
    at com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:107)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:369)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:354)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:280)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:235)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue. See here:
https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/3995

Edit: if you don't need Hazelcast you can disable it as follows:

```
./bin/asadmin set-hazelcast-configuration --enabled=false
```

(or change the Hazelcast port if you need VNC)

Edit2: for the next version of Payara you will be able to change the Hazelcast port directly on creation of the domain: https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/4270

Comment: Thanks! Uninstalling VNC Solved my problem. I already tried ending it with taskmanager. It auto restarts itself and blocks port 5900.

Comment: @christoph-john I get with `./bin/asadmin set-hazelcast-configuration --enabled=false` 
Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848]. Is the server up?
No such local command: set-hazelcast-configuration.  Unable to access the server to execute the command remotely.  Verify the server is available.
Command set-hazelcast-configuration failed.
%

Comment: @joseluisbz what happens when Payara is running when issuing the command?

Comment: @ChristophJohn ahh OK, when Payara is running works... `% sh payara5-2020-3/bin/asadmin set-hazelcast-configuration --startport=5902`
*Command set-hazelcast-configuration executed successfully.*
`%`The configuration is detected. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve the problem. Make sure TightVNCServer is not blocking port 5900. Just ending it with Task Manager doesnt work. It will auto restart. In my case only uninstalling helped to unblock port 5900 and run glassfish payara server.

Answer (score 1):

On MAC under system preferences, disabled screen sharing and restart your server (Glassfish or tomcat), it worked for me.