# Payara Server 5 is not starting by Console on macOS/Windows

Tags: windows, macos, startup, payara

In **`macOS`**, I was trying to use `Payara Server` with `Netbeans 12` and I got:

```
Launching Payara Server on Felix platform
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@462c1ddf in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/payara5-2020-4/glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/payara5-2020-4/glassfish/lib/templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/payara5-2020-4/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/payara5-2020-4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties
  Running Payara Version: Payara Server  5.2020.4 #badassfish (build 817)|#]
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter|#]
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.2.Final|#]
  [192.168.0.11]:4900 [development] [3.12.6] Connection[id=1, /192.168.0.11:49587->/192.168.0.11:5900, qualifier=null, endpoint=[192.168.0.11]:5900, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=1, /192.168.0.11:49587->/192.168.0.11:5900, qualifier=null, endpoint=[192.168.0.11]:5900, alive=true, type=NONE], thread=hz._hzInstance_1_development.IO.thread-in-0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: RFB
    at com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:107)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:369)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:354)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:280)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:235)
|#]
```

Then by console, here my position (I renamed `payara5` directory to `payara5-2020-4`).

```
% pwd
.../payara5-2020-4/glassfish/bin
%
```

In order to fix the first problem:

```
% ./asadmin set-hazelcast-configuration --enabled=false
Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848]. Is the server up?
No such local command: set-hazelcast-configuration.  Unable to access the server to execute the command remotely.  Verify the server is available.
Command set-hazelcast-configuration failed.
%
```

After I was trying to up...

```
% ./asadmin start-domain domain1
Waiting for domain1 to start ..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
No response from the Domain Administration Server (domain1) after 600 seconds.
The command is either taking too long to complete or the server has failed.
Please see the server log files for command status.  
Please start with the --verbose option in order to see early messages.
Command start-domain failed.
%
```

Then, I was trying to verbose option (like recommendation)...

```
% ./asadmin start-domain domain1  --verbose
Command start-domain only accepts one operand
...

% ./asadmin --verbose start-domain domain1
Invalid option: --verbose
...

% ./asadmin -v start-domain domain1       
Invalid option: -v
...

% ./asadmin start-domain domain1  -v       
Command start-domain only accepts one operand
...
```

The common message

```
Usage: asadmin [asadmin-utility-options] start-domain
    [-v|--verbose[=<verbose(default:false)>]]
    [--upgrade[=<upgrade(default:false)>]]
    [-w|--watchdog[=<watchdog(default:false)>]]
    [-d|--debug[=<debug(default:false)>]]
    [-n|--dry-run[=<dry-run(default:false)>]]
    [--drop-interrupted-commands[=<drop-interrupted-commands(default:false)>]]
    [--prebootcommandfile <prebootcommandfile>]
    [--postbootcommandfile <postbootcommandfile>] [--domaindir <domaindir>]
    [-?|--help[=<help(default:false)>]] [domain_name]
```

Sadly, I believe strongly that `Payara` is inmature product.

**But, How Can I solve all these errors/mistakes?**

**EDIT:**

I was testing on **`Windows 10 PRO`** with `Netbeans 12`

```
Launching Payara Server on Felix platform
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@586f5c68 in service registry.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
Caused by: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. com.sun.enterprise.module.ResolveError: Failed to start OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector [102]], State = [NEW]
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load descriptor SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.batch.spi.impl.BatchRuntimeConfigurationInjector
    name=batch-runtime-configuration
    contracts={org.glassfish.batch.spi.impl.BatchRuntimeConfigurationInjector,org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigInjector}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={org.jvnet.hk2.config.InjectionTarget}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=@table-suffix={optional,default\:,datatype\:java.lang.String,leaf},@data-source-lookup-name={optional,datatype\:java.lang.String,leaf},@table-prefix={optional,default\:,datatype\:java.lang.String,leaf},@schema-name={optional,default\:APP,datatype\:java.lang.String,leaf},@executor-service-lookup-name={optional,default\:concurrent/__defaultManagedExecutorService,datatype\:java.lang.String,leaf},target={org.glassfish.batch.spi.impl.BatchRuntimeConfiguration},Bundle-SymbolicName={fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector},Bundle-Version={5.2020.4}
    rank=0
    loader=OsgiPopulatorPostProcessor.HK2Loader(OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector [102]], State = [NEW],1228963996)
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=170
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=373437697
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.loadClass(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2247)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:438)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:457)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.DomDocument$InjectionTargetFilter.matches(DomDocument.java:184)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getDescriptors(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:347)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getDescriptors(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:389)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getBestDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:397)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.DomDocument.buildModel(DomDocument.java:135)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigModel.parseValue(ConfigModel.java:959)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigModel.<init>(ConfigModel.java:875)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.DomDocument.buildModel(DomDocument.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.DomDocument.getModelByElementName(DomDocument.java:162)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.handleElement(ConfigParser.java:165)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:101)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.config.support.DomainXml.parseDomainXml(DomainXml.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.config.support.DomainXml.run(DomainXml.java:121)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigurationPopulator.populateConfig(ConfigurationPopulator.java:58)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.bootstrap.HK2Populator.populateConfig(HK2Populator.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.populateConfig(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Main.createServiceLocator(Main.java:249)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.HK2Main.createServiceLocator(HK2Main.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime.newGlassFish(EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishRuntimeDecorator.newGlassFish(GlassFishRuntimeDecorator.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntime.newGlassFish(OSGiGlassFishRuntime.java:91)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:125)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.module.ResolveError: Failed to start OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector [102]], State = [NEW]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl.start(OSGiModuleImpl.java:193)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OsgiPopulatorPostProcessor$1.loadClass(OsgiPopulatorPostProcessor.java:54)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.loadClass(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2239)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector [102](R 102.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector [102](R 102.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.ibm.jbatch.spi) [caused by: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.batch.payara-jbatch [311](R 311.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.batch.payara-jbatch [311](R 311.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.weld) [caused by: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.web.weld-integration [372](R 372.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.web.weld-integration [372](R 372.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor)(version>=5.2020.0)(!(version>=6.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.web.glue [360](R 360.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.web.glue [360](R 360.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.catalina)(version>=5.2020.0)(!(version>=6.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.web.core [358](R 358.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.web.core [358](R 358.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.web.loader)(version>=5.2020.0)(!(version>=6.0.0)))]]]] Unresolved requirements: [[fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector [102](R 102.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.ibm.jbatch.spi)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl.startBundle(OSGiModuleImpl.java:227)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl.start(OSGiModuleImpl.java:185)
    ... 33 more
Completed shutdown of GlassFish runtime
We are in non-embedded mode, so fish.payara.server.internal.core.glassfish [113] has nothing to do.
```

Comment: Hi, the technical documentation for the start-domain command explains that any options go after the command but before the last unnamed option which is the domain name. You should run `asadmin start-domain -v domain1`. You can also run just `asadmin start-domain -v` because `domain1` is the default domain.

Comment: It looks like you hit the known issue on Mac OS, where Payara Server's Hazelcast port collides with the port of VNC (Remote Desktop): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521647/payara5-server-will-not-deploy-unknown-protocol-rfb. This is already raised as an issue here: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/4670. A quick solution is to change the NVC port or Payara Server's Hazelcast port, see my answer.

Comment: I recommend raising the second issue (BundleException) on github: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues. it's hard to answer 2 different questions here on StackOverflow and it's rather an issue that requires a reproducer anyway. It probably happens only on Windows and maybe only under certain configuration that happens to be in your environment.

Comment: Payara Server Community Edition is currently being developed at a fast pace, preparing for the upcoming changes in Jakarta EE 9 and refactoring some code to improve performance. This may cause some issues. I recommend raising any issue on github and try an older versions like 5.2020.3 if it works for you.

Comment: @OndroMih Yeah, I download from https://search.maven.org/artifact/fish.payara.distributions/payara the versions: `payara-5.194`, `payara-5.201`, `payara-5.2020.2` and `payara-5-2020.3`, and they works

Comment: @OndroMih Unfortunately on macOS I haven't same results.
`sh payara5-2020-3/bin/asadmin set-hazelcast-configuration --enabled=false` or  `sh payara5-2020-3/bin/asadmin set-hazelcast-configuration --startport=5901` I get *Command set-hazelcast-configuration not found. 
Check the entry of command name. This command may be provided by a package that is not installed.
Command set-hazelcast-configuration failed.*

Comment: @OndroMih I changed the line `<hazelcast-runtime-configuration start-port="5901"></hazelcast-runtime-configuration>` on the file `domain.xml` located on `payaraFolder/glassfish/domains/domain1/config` Like you tell me in your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Alternatively I tested this option disabling VNC (macOS built in) like this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/314418/262030 and works with the same port 5900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Unknown protocol: RFB" is coming from the Hazelcast component, which is trying to discover other cluster instances that could be running on port 5900. In some operating systems, very often on Mac, this port is occupied by VNC (remote desktop), which responds to Payara Server in an unexpected way.

There's a solution covered for Payara Enterprise users in the Payara Knowledge Base. I have access to it and will copy the relevant parts from it here.

There are various solutions possible:

- Stop the process that occupies the port 5900 (e.g. VNC, which uses that port by default). Alternatively, you can change its port. Payara Server should then start OK.
- Configure Payara Server to use a different port for Hazelcast. If you run Payara Server according to the above solution, you can then run command: `asadmin set-hazelcast-configuration --startport=5901`.
- Directly edit the `domain.xml` in the directory `glassfish/domains/domain1/config` and change the port 5900 to something else. Then run Payara Server as usual.
- Or change the Hazelcast port of Payara Server at startup. First, create a text file `config.txt` with one line `set-hazelcast-configuration --startport=5901`. Then start Payara Server with `asdamin start-domain --postbootcommandfile config.txt`. More on this in the documentation: https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.2020.4/documentation/payara-micro/asadmin/pre-and-post-boot-scripts.html

Comment: I was trying on **asadmin** console
`% sh payara5-2020-3/bin/asadmin`                       
*Use "exit" to exit and "help" for online help.
Remote commands not fetched*
`asadmin> set-hazelcast-configuration --startport=5901`
*Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848]. Is the server up?
No such local command: set-hazelcast-configuration.  Unable to access the server to execute the command remotely.  Verify the server is available.
Command set-hazelcast-configuration failed.*
`asadmin>`

Comment: set-hazelcast-configuration is a remote command. This means it needs to connect to a running Payara server which then executes the command. If you can't run Payara Server successfully, you can't run any remote command on it. A solution is to run the command in a post boot script passed to the start-domain command when you start Payara Server. Or directly edit domain.xml before running Payara Server.